# Getting call records in android

Tags: android, listview, phone-call

I have used Calllogs.calls method and fetched the contact and the details but i am getting all the call records in a single string Using this code.

```
  private void getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n---------------------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();

    String s= sb.toString();
    String[] array;



    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=1; i<40; i++){
        if(s.contains("Phone Number")){
            array=s.split("Phone Number");
           list.add(array[i - 1]);


        }
    }
```

Now i want to split all the contacts individually with particular details and display them in Listview.How can i split them and set them in custom listview. I want it to be like My operator follow ups page as shown in the link.

```
  [This is how i want it to be][1]
```

Comment: Create an object and store the details there instead of appending to sb

Comment: please ellaborate.

Comment: Create an object with the details, e.g. number, type, date etc. Then instead of appending to sb, create 1 object for each call log with the details stored in the vars. When you got the list of objects you can create a custom adapter to show them in a ListView.

Comment: Ok. I will try to do it this way.

Comment: sorry,, maybe this is not your answer that you looking for,, i m deleting my answer

Comment: But i marked your answer as correct. A little help would be appreciated. i need to do exactly the same but i have done it some other way as shown above. I will implement your code once i understand it clearly.please repost this time more clearly.